# Image fading too slowly

Tags: jquery, delay

I have a image, when I hover on the image it takes about 3 seconds till it fades in. I want it that it's going to fade in instantly. Here's a snippet of my jquery:

```
$cache.mouseenter(function(){
    $cache.fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
});
```

Comment: Can you show some fiddle.

Comment: 3 seconds seems to be a lot of time, are you sure that's the only code running?

Comment: Yes, i tried it on my localhost and on my webserver.

Comment: The first argument in `fadeTo` is the length of the animation in milliseconds, if you pass a small number (say 200) and it still takes 3 seconds, you have a problem elsewhere.

Comment: Can you isolate this in a Codepen or JSFiddle? That will help narrow the possible issues down, and get you a better answer : )

Comment: This works fine on its own.  Something else must be causing the issue. http://jsfiddle.net/UcXfe/1/